# How can I check if a String contains X letters and Y numbers?

Tags: java, string

I'm developing an application where the user will insert an vehicle ID.

At our country, the ID is always 3 letters and 4 numbers.

How can I check if a `String` has X numbers and Y letters in Java?

Comment: Can the letters and numbers be interleaved? Or is there some structure in them?

Comment: How is it you can have 2600 rep but still ask a question like this. Have you tried anything? Post your code.

Comment: Have vou tryed to use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: Jeez, folks are being pretty rude today!  Anyway, the obvious solution - as A4L pointed out - is to use a regex.

Comment: This isn't about being rude. Its about you being a good SO citizen. There is an expectation that people put at least some minimal effort into trying something before asking a question.

Comment: i provided no non regex answer. maybe not the most efficient but straight forward to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply work with regular expressions. Something like:

```
if(vehicleId.matches("^[A-Z]{3}\d{4}$"))
```

(Assuming the id contains three capital letters followed by four digits.)

This will return a boolean if `vehicleId`, supposedly a variable holding the user's input, is matched.

Comment: I am not too sure if we can positively assume that we are talking only of uppercase letters…

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg We probably can't, but I assumed so because at least where I live and I think in most of Europe we only use capital letters. But you're right. I'll wait for OP to add details.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions for this problem. I'll not give you a full solution but will try to guide you.

One solution would be iterating on the string char-by-char. The [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class contains many useful methods for this task.

Other solution would be using a regex and [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) non digits characters (`\D`) with the empty string. From here the way to the answer is very short.

Visit the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API and the [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) tutorial to fuel your creative fire.